# Zedgraph Control accessible from any function

Tags: c#, charts, zedgraph

I have this function:

```
public void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GraphPane myPane = GRAPH.GraphPane;
}
```

Where myPane is a reference to GraphPane (GRAPH is name of ZedGraphControl which is displayed in GUI)
And now I want to change things like name of "x" or "y" axis, title, colors etd. or whatever you can change, but based on events. For example: I have textbox where I can write text and this text will be displayed in graph as title after textbox_textchanged_event trigger like this:

```
void TitleTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myPane.Title.Text = textbox1.Text;
}
```

There will be more functions like this to change properties of the graph. But this is not working.
Is there a way to come around this?
I have also tried this:

```
void TitleTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GRAPH.GraphPane.Title.Text = textbox1.text.Text;
}
```

but no help at all. 
Please help, any advices are welcome.

**ANSWER:
So far, i have found this solution:

```
public void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EditGraph(GRAPH);

}
```

This is the event that handles text change in text box:

```
public void TB_GRAPH_TITLE_VALUETextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //GraphPane myPane2 = GRAPH.GraphPane;
    changedGraphTitle = true;
    EditGraph(GRAPH);           
}
```

This is the function that find what is changed and update it:

```
public void EditGraph(ZedGraphControl zgc)
{
    GraphPane myPane = zgc.GraphPane;
    if(changedGraphTitle)
    {
       myPane.Title.Text =  TB_GRAPH_TITLE_VALUE.Text;
       changedGraphTitle = false;   
       zgc.Refresh();
    }
}
```

"bool changedGraphTitle = false" must be declared also.**

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, here's my simple code to update Zedgraph Axis Titles by a single ButtonClick event.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using ZedGraph;

 namespace updateZedGraph
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
        myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;
      }

      GraphPane myPane; 

      private void btn_UpdateChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        // Update x Axis Text
        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = textBox1.Text;

        // Update x Axis Text
        myPane.YAxis.Title.Text = textBox2.Text;

        // Refresh Chart
        zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
      }
  }
}
```

[image]

hope that helps..